# Publishing Artifacts without a Build

Tags: jenkins

How can I upload binaries straight to Jenkins without running a build?
For example, I want to use a customized maven, without deploying it to all of my nodes.
Is there a neat way to somehow upload this zip straight to Jenkins? Without running a build that has a publish artifacts step?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is built for keeping the artifacts that come out of a build job. It's not built for just uploading artifacts without building.

For what you want to do, use an artifact repository server like [JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/), [Sonatype Nexus](https://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Archiva](https://archiva.apache.org). These are built exactly for that purpose.

Comment: Strange, in anthillPro it was something built-in. I thought that maybe Jenkins has some plugin for that purpose.